# adding 2d array column data together?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, 2d

if you could possibly point me to the right direction, that would be great. i have tried researching about this but found no solution.

i have a 2d array which holds student name and 3 grades (eng, maths, science.)

student array (24,3)

Now, i would like to use the data which is held within the array to create averages.

I need a total class average for: maths column, eng column, and science. I also need an overall average for all subjects.

the code i have used, so far, brings some odd results.

```
studentarray(i,1) / count 
studentarray(i,2) / count

studentarray(i,3) / count

totalaverage = (studentarray(i,1) + studentarray(i,2) + studentarray(i,3)) / count
```

the first 3 averages only give me result of the first entry within the array. then the calculation will just display the data shown within the 3 columns, eg 101010.

any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Function CalcSubjectAverage(ByVal studentArray(,) As Integer, ByVal subject As Integer) As Single
    Dim total As Single
    For i As Integer = 0 To studentArray.Length
        total += studentArray(i, 0)
    Next

    Return total / studentArray.Length
End Function
```

You need to add the subjects up first, then you can calculate the average :)

Comment: If my answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as answered, by pressing the checkmark button :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one also helps:

I have provided necessary comments in the code.

Code:
    ' this are 2D dynamic arrays
    ' StudentArray(,) for storage of data of student grades
    ' Ave_Values_per_Subject(,) for storing average values
    ' Ave_Values_per_Student()
    ' actually you can use only the first array, but to make the codes more understandable, _
    ' we declare another 2 arrays
    Dim StudentArray(,), Ave_Values_per_Subject(,), Ave_Values_per_Student() As Object
    ' this is the function
    Sub SolveMyProblem(ByVal Num_of_Students As UInteger, ByVal Num_of_Subjects As UInteger)

```
    ' get the number of students and resize the array
    ReDim StudentArray(Num_of_Students - 1, Num_of_Subjects - 1), Ave_Values_per_Subject(0, Num_of_Subjects - 1), _
          Ave_Values_per_Student(Num_of_Students - 1)
    ' you can imagine this as having a table with Num_of_Students as the number of rows and Num_of_Subjects as the _
    ' number of columns
    ' StudentArray(0,0) gives the value of student #1 at subject #1 (say english) _
    ' StudentArray(0,1) gives the value of student #1 at subject #2 (say math) _
    ' StudentArray(1,3) gives the value of student #2 at subject #3 (say science) and so on

    ' example: we have 4 students with english, math, and science as subjects
    ' thus Num_of_Students = 4 and Num_of_Subjects = 3 giving us StudentArray(3,2) and Ave_Values_per_Subject(0,2)
    ' Suppose the grades of student #1 for english, math, and science are 70, 80, and 90 respectively; _
    ' student #2 = {75, 80, 90}; student #3 = {75, 85, 95}; and student #4 = {60, 100, 85}
    ' Suppose index 0 of StudentArray (StudentArray(0,0)) represents english subject; _
    ' StudentArray (0,1) = math; and StudentArray (0,2) = science

    '' to calculate for the average of students for EACH subject and to store it in a separate array:
    For subjectCount = 0 To UBound(StudentArray, 2)
        Dim SumPerSubject As Single
        For studentCount = 0 To UBound(StudentArray, 1)
            SumPerSubject += StudentArray(studentCount, subjectCount)
        Next
        ' average of students per subject:
        Ave_Values_per_Subject(0, subjectCount) = SumPerSubject / (UBound(StudentArray, 1) + 1)
        ' the average of students per subject is determined and stored in the above array
        ' this means that the average of values for english is stored in Ave_Values_per_Subject(0,0) _
        ' Ave_Values_per_Subject(0,1) for math; and Ave_Values_per_Subject(0,2) for science
    Next

    '' to calculate for the average of EACH student on all subjects:
    For studentCount = 0 To UBound(StudentArray, 1)
        Dim SumPerStudent As Single
        For subjectCount = 0 To UBound(StudentArray, 2)
            SumPerStudent += StudentArray(studentCount, subjectCount)
        Next
        ' ave values of each student on all subjects:
        Ave_Values_per_Student(studentCount) = SumPerStudent / 3
    Next
End Sub
```